# Jaxb : IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am getting the following exception "1 counts of `IllegalAnnotationExceptions`"

Code:

```
Image image = new Image("url");
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Image.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(image, sw);
```

Class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ProductImage")
public class Image {

    private String url;

    public Image( String url) {   
        this.url = url;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "ImageLocation")
    public String getUrl() {
        return this.url;
    }
}
```

I tried setting the `@XmlElement` annotation on the field and setting AccessorType Field on the class. But I am getting the same exception.

---

I was missing the default constructor. 
public Image () {
}

Comment: What is the stack trace for the exception you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Class..

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name="ProductImage")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlType(name = "ProductImage", propOrder = {
    "url"
})
public class Image {

    public Image(){}

    private String url;

    public Image( String url) {   
        this.url = url;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "ImageLocation")
    public String getUrl() {
        return this.url;
    }
}
```

XML generated is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ProductImage>
    <ImageLocation>url</ImageLocation>
</ProductImage>
```